# Is surjectivity preserved in open neighborhoods?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves

Let $X,S$ be schemes of finite type over a field and let $f:X\times S\to S$ be the projection. Suppose we have a morphism of coherent sheaves $\phi:\mathscr E\to \mathscr F$ on $X\times S$.

> Is it true that if the restriction $\phi|_{X\times\{s\}}$ to the fiber
>   over $s$ is surjective (or injective), then there is an open
>   neighborhood $U\subset S$ of $s$ such that $\phi|_{X\times U}$ is
>   surjective (or injective)?

A similar statement is true for stalks: for a locally noetherian scheme $S$, if a morphism of coherent $\mathscr O_S$-modules is such that $\phi_s:\mathscr E_s\to \mathscr F_s$ is surjective at $s$, then it is surjective in a neighborhood of $s$.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler to consider the support of the kernel or cokernel sheaf, call it $\mathscr G$ -- we wish to show that it vanishes appropriately.

**Edit:** the original argument I posted was incorrect (I'll leave it for posterity; see below and in the comments...). Here is a simpler argument:

The statement is false in general without some kind of properness assumption. For example, if $X = S = \mathbb{A}^1$, then the structure sheaf of the hyperbola $\{xs = 1\}$ is zero on the fiber $s = 0$ but is nonzero on every other fiber.

However, if $X$ is complete, then $f : X \times S \to S$ is proper (more generally, if $f : \mathcal{X} \to S$ is any proper map), then we can make the following argument: let $Z$ be the support locus of $\mathscr G$. Then $Z$ is closed because $\mathscr G$ is coherent. By properness, $f(Z)$ is closed in $S$, and by hypothesis $s \notin f(Z)$. Consequently, $U = S - f(Z)$ is an open neighborhood of $s$ and $\mathscr G|_{f^{-1}(U)} = 0$.

**(Original argument:)**

We can assume $S$ is affine; and we can actually just have $\mathcal{X} \to S$ be any finite type $S$-scheme.

Now the statement is: if a sheaf vanishes on the fiber over $s \in S$, we wish to show that it vanishes on the preimage of a neighborhood of $s$. At this point we can also assume $X$ is affine (reason: cover with finitely-many affine opens, solve the problem there, and intersect the corresponding opens of $S$...)

Now we're reduced to an easy commutative algebra statement! For $B$ a finitely-generated $A$-algebra and $M$ a finite $B$-module, if $M \otimes A_P = 0$, then there exists $f\notin P$ ($f \in A$) such that $M \otimes A[1/f] = 0$. I leave this part to you.

Comment: The restriction in the question says in your language, $M\otimes_A A/P=0$ for a maximal ideal $P$ corresponding to the closed point $p$. This does not imply the necessary vanishing. In general, the statement is true only if  $X$ is complete.

Comment: Oops, you're completely right. I guess if $X$ is complete, then $f_* \mathscr F$ is coherent, so Nakayama actually applies and gets us up to the stalk...

Comment: I was thinking about applying Nakayama, but I could not get there. Is $X$ complete enough? Don't we need the morphism $f:X\to S$ to be proper to get $f_\ast\mathscr F$ coherent?

Comment: $X$ is complete if and only if the projection $f:X\times S\to S$ is proper for all $S$.

Comment: Sure. But in Jake's answer the context had changed, and a general morphism $X\to S$ replaced my projection $X\times S\to S$. For the original case it's fine.

Comment: Brenin: if $X$ is complete, any morphism out of it is proper. So that's certainly sufficient to imply $X \to S$ being proper. But it's enough for the morphism itself to proper, even if the source isn't.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Every morphism out of it to a separated thing is proper :o)

Comment: Dear Jake, I wonder why in the last statement you require $M\otimes_AA_P=0$ instead of $M\otimes_AA/P=0$. Would not the sheaf version be $f_\ast \mathscr F\otimes_{\mathscr O_S}k(s)=0$?

Comment: @Brenin: I thought incorrectly that we could get to $M \otimes A_P = 0$ from $M \otimes A/P = 0$ (by Nakayama), but it wasn't true (since $M$ isn't finitely-generated). Hence the ensuing corrections...

Comment: @AlexYoucis :-)

Comment: To those still reading this: let $Z$ be the support of $\mathscr F$, which is closed since $\mathscr F$ is coherent. Assuming the map to $S$ is proper, we get $f(Z)$ closed in $S$, and by hypothesis $s \notin f(Z)$. So the neighborhood $U = S - f(Z)$ works. (Someone should check me on this! :) )

Comment: @JakeLevinson: Sorry for keeping bothering you, but I am a bit confused. So is this the final argument? Because it seems to me that if $f$ is proper then $M$ is f.g. over $A$ too and then one could apply Nakayama, am I wrong? Would you mind modifying your answer with your final argument, before I accept it? Thanks again and have a nice day :)

Comment: @Brenin: This argument actually just stands on its own -- particularly since it's simpler than all the previous attempts... I'll edit the post.

Comment: @Brenin: if we use an open cover of $X$ to get the module $M$, then we can't assume it is finitely-generated over $S$, no -- this is the same problem as before. Properness is a global property of $f$ in this sense (though it is local on the base $S$). In fact, I'm not sure any of the arguments involving $f_*\mathscr F$ are correct, since $f_*\mathscr F$ may be zero even if $\mathscr F$ is not... focusing on the support of $\mathscr F$ is clearer to me.